# Why does the standard library have find and find_if?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Couldn't `find_if` just be an overload of `find`? That's how `std::binary_search` and friends do it...

Comment: `std::binary_search` doesn't sometimes take a value, and sometimes a *Predicate*, it *always* takes a value, and optionally a *Compare*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A predicate is a valid thing to find, so you could arrive at ambiguities.

---

Consider `find_if` is renamed `find`, then you have:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename T>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value);

template <typename InputIterator, typename Predicate>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);
```

What shall be done, then, with:

```
find(c.begin(), c.end(), x); // am I finding x, or using x to find?
```

Rather than try to come up with some convoluted solution to differentiate based on `x` (which can't always be done*), it's easier just to separate them.

*This would be ambiguous, no matter what your scheme is or how powerful it might be†:

```
struct foo
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T&);
};

bool operator==(const foo&, const foo&);

std::vector<foo> v = /* ... */;
foo f = /* ... */; 

// f can be used both as a value and as a predicate
find(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
```

†Save mind reading.

Comment: @GManNickG, by _ambiguity_ do you mean that the compiler is not be able to select one over the other, or that it will choose based on the `const`/non-`const`-ness of the third argument (and regardless of it being a predicate or a value, since one can be both, as you said)? My conclusion is the latter, for the simple reason that the lines `template<typename T> void f(const T&) { cout << "const T&\n"; };` and `template<typename T> void f(T&) { cout << "T&\n"; };` are compilable together, and they can both be used (passing literals/`const` calls the former, passing non-`const` calls the latter).

Answer (score 4):

Here's what Stroustrup said (The C++ Programming Language, 18.5.2):

> If `find()` and `find_if()` had the
>   same name, surprising abmiguities
>   would have resulted. In general, the
>   `_if` suffix is used to indicate that
>   an algrithm takes a predicate.

As to what exactly that "ambiguity" is, Steve Jessop answered that in his (top rated) answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656618/how-to-stdfind-using-a-compare-object).

(note: that question may actually qualify as the same question as this one. I'm not quite smart enough in C++ arcania to decide).

Answer (score 2):

It can't have the same name because there would be an ambiguity. Suppose that we had a `find` overload instead of `find_if`. Then suppose:

```
// Pseudo-code
struct finder
{
    bool operator()(const T&) const { ... }
    bool operator==(const finder& right) const { ... }
}

std::vector<finder> finders;

finder my_finder;

std::find(finders.begin(), finders.end(), my_finder);
```

The `find` would have no way to resolve the inconsistency: Should it attempt to find the `finder` in the container, or *use* the `finder` to do the find operation? To solve this problem they created two function names.

Answer (score -2):

You can certainly implement `find` in terms of `find_if` using some sort of equality predicate.

I would guess that the real reason is that you can implement `find` fairly easily and provide performant specialised implementations for typical encountered types; if you are using `find_if`, the predicate you pass in can be arbitrarily complex, which gives the library implementer less scope of optimisation.

Also, C++ has the philosphy of "you don't pay for what you don't use" and you'd normally expect that you don't want to pay for a predicate evaluation if a simple comparison will do.

Comment: The question isn't about implementing one in terms of the other, but why `find_if` isn't an overload of find that takes a predicate.